# Using collective communication in MPI to recieve results

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am receiving results from multiple processes in a for-loop. The result is various parts of a vector.

```
for (int d= 1; d<= num; d++)
    {
      MPI_Recv(&result, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, d, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
```

So ideally I would create a vector like an int[] v=new int[num] and put all the values returned by the Recv into it, But using the function `MPI_Recv` it needs to be in a for-loop. Is there a way to use the collective communication method `MPI_Reduce` to do this and avoid the for loop?
For the worker process with rank=0 I added this line:

```
  double *c = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
MPI_Gather(NULL, 0, MPI_DOUBLE,
               c, total_rows + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

For all other processes the following line is executed:

```
 MPI_Gather(result, total_rows, MPI_DOUBLE,
               NULL, total_rows + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

where double *result is a double* with total_rows elements
But there is something wrong with this. As my code is not working properly. Each of the worker processes is storing a part of the vector. The root process needs to generate the complete vector.
Any suggestions on the usage of MPI_Gather?

Comment: Yes, MPI_Gather()

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Is it necessary to use MPI_Scatter() if one wants to use MPI_Gather()?

Comment: this is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Please post that as an answer I will accept it

Comment: you changed your question since I replied to it. The new issue is that `MPI_Gather()` requires rank 0 sends and receive the same amount of data. Since you are not sending anything from rank 0, you can either use `MPI_Gatherv()` or `MPI_Gather(sendbuf=MPI_IN_PLACE, ..., recvbuf = results - total_rows - 1, ...)`